The volume of the parallelepiped
Prove that for any vectors $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by these vectors is $\langle\gamma,\alpha\times\beta\rangle$.
That's what I got:
Let $\alpha=(a_1,a_2,a_3), \beta=(b_1,b_2,b_3), \gamma=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$. Then:
$\alpha\times\beta=(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_2 & a_3\\
  b_2 & b_3\\
\end{vmatrix},
-\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_3\\
  b_1 & b_3\\
\end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2\\
  b_1 & b_2\\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{array})$
$|\langle\gamma,\alpha\times\beta\rangle|=|(\begin{array}{c}
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_2 & a_3\\
  b_2 & b_3\\
\end{vmatrix}c_1,
-\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_3\\
  b_1 & b_3\\
\end{vmatrix}c_2,
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2\\
  b_1 & b_2\\
\end{vmatrix}c_3|)=\begin{vmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
  b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
  c_1 & c_2 & c_3\\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{array}$
Everywhere I see it is used as a well-known fact that this is what we are looking for, but we only mentioned that the volume is the determinant of the Gram matrix. What should I do now?

You may find this useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243126/determination-of-the-volume-of-a-parallelepiped

yeah, I saw it and it's all clear, but I don't know how to connect it with Gram matrix

The problem is clear if the vectors are orthogonal, right?

What you wrote is not correct.

why its not? :(

It seems like you know what is true regarding the relationship between determinants and parallelepiped volume. But you want to know why. Here's the way I like to think about it.
The case of a diagonal matrix (where the vectors forming the parallelepiped lie along the coordinate axes, and so actually form a rectangular prism) is pretty clear, I think. Say $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the canonical basis, where $e_i$ has $i^{th}$ coordinate $1$ and all other coordinates equal to zero and $x_i=c_ie_i$. Then the Gram matrix ix the diagonal matrix $$\text{diag}(c_1,\ldots, c_n)=\begin{pmatrix} c_1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & c_2 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & c_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the length of $x_i$ is $|c_i|$ and the absolute value of the determinant is $$|c_1c_2\ldots c_n|=|c_1||c_2|\ldots|c_n|.$$
In the general case, we can perform one step of the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure. We note that 1. this does not affect the determinant, and it also does not affect the volume of the parallelepiped.
That is, say we have vectors $$Y_1,\ldots, Y_n.$$ This generates a parallelpiped $Y$ and the matrix $M_Y$ with columns $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ has a determinant. We can perform one steo of Gram-Schmidt to get $Z_1,\ldots, Z_n$. These vectors generate a (different) parallelepiped $Z$ and we have a new matrix $M_Z$ with columns $Z_1,\ldots, Z_n$. One can check (and understand intuitively why it is true) that the parallelepipeds $Y,Z$ have the same volume and why the matrices $M_Y,M_Z$ have the same determinants.
So if we start with $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ and keep going until we get to $u_1,\ldots, u_n$, which are orthogonal, we understand why the last parallelepiped (which is a rectangular prism) has volume equal to the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix with columns $u_1,\ldots, u_n$. By applying the previous paragraph repeatedly, we see why the absolute value of the determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped for every intermediate step, all the way back to the first, which is $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ (the one we wanted to know about).
As an example: Imagine a stack of books that's stacked diagonally. If you look at it on the side, you see a parallelogram. What's the volume (or, in this example, area) of the parallelogram? Well, we would "straighten up" the stack, so that it's not a parallelogram anymore: It's a rectangle. Then calculate the area of the rectangle. This is a height times the base (same height and base as the parallelogram). The difference is that after straightening, one vector forming the rectangle is the base, and the other is the height. This wasn't true of the parallelogram. The parallelogram had one vector forming the base (the same vector and the same base as the rectangle), but the other vector tells us the slant height of the parallelogram, not its height. The geometric reality of the Gram-Schmidt procedure (which is what straightening the stack of books is in this case) takes the slant height vector, decomposes it into one piece orthogonal to the base and another parallel to it, and then simply discards the parallel piece.
In three dimensions it's similar. We first "rectify" one dimension with respect to the face formed by the other two, and then move into that face and do something similar (working within a 2-d subspace of the 3-d space).

yeah, it helps to gain more intuition, but I don't see how it relates to my question.

In what way is my answer not a direct answer to the question you asked?
